# Drag an Item from a ListView and drop an Image on a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

Right now I am learning `c#` and I tried to make a functionality for drag and drop. I want to drag an item from a ListView (a text) which on drop will transform in an Image in a Panel control.

The images are saved in the project's in `bin/Debug` directory.

Until now, I've managed to drag and drop text to text or image to image from an external source (images from my desktop or text from an internet page).

This is not what I wanted to have in my Form. I want to take the text with drag, add an extension in the function (`.png`) and drop the image on the Panel.

This is a [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/nrc96v) from my application. On the left I have a ListView with text, on the right I have a Panel.
Right now the panel has an welcome `BackgroundImage`, but when I do drag and drop I want it to have a `BackgroundImage` of the specific application from the left.

This is the code I have now. With this I can take images from my desktop but not the text from ListView.

```
private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    foreach (string pic in (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)) {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(pic);
        panel1.BackgroundImage = img;
    }
}

private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    listView1.DoDragDrop(listView1.SelectedItems,
        DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Comment: With ListView using the `ItemDrag` event is recommended.

Comment: And what should this event do? Please tell me how do I  use it

Comment: What do you have in `SelectedItem`? Why are you using `DataFormats.FileDrop`? You should check whether the dragged DataObject contains something you can/want to handle: see: [DataObject.GetDataPresent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataobject.getdatapresent). Also, see: [DataObject.SetFileDropList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataobject.setfiledroplist).

Comment: You would use it instead of the MouseDown. - @preciousbetine shows you how to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Add the following events to your code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.AllowDrop = true;
}

private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{    
    listView1.DoDragDrop(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text , DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile((string)e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)) + ".png");
}

private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but nothing happens. I drag the text but when I drop nothing changes on the panel.

Comment: This should work, provided the path needs no more info. But I suggest adding a few checks: `if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;` and `string fn = "prefix?" + (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) + ".png"; if (File.Exists(fn))... `.